# Getting attribute value form varying attribute name

Tags: xml, powershell

Suppose this XML:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c abc="atext1a" def="atext1b">text1</c>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c ghi="atext2a" jkl="atext2b">text2</c>
    </b>
</a>
```

How would I select the values of the first attribute? (`atext1a` and `atext2a`)

The problem here is that the attribute names change and all the answers I found are for the same attribute names.

`$att = $xml.selectNodes("//c[@*]")` doesn't work and lists this, as I guess it expects the same attribute names:

```
abc     def     #text
---     ---     -----
atext1a atext1b text1
                text2
```

Comment: `$xml.SelectNodes('//c[@*]').ForEach({$_.Attributes[0].Value})`

Comment: Thanks. (before asking I was trying `foreach($a in $atts){$a.Attribute}` to get any attributes (could select column with [] then), but it didn't return anything back. Turns out it's plural.)